# Set two div in the same line to display in the center

Tags: html, css

I have two div, which stay in the same line already but it's not in the center of page. I try to do it but I can't.
Here is the code:

```css
.table-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box-1 {
  background: url(../images/_C008.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #374140;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-1">
  <div class="box-1">
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <p>Au quotidien, la vie de l’atelier est organisée autour des tâches minutieuses de chacun et tous sont conscients que l’excellence est le résultat d’un travail d’équipe.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to center it vertically?

Comment: give `.table-1` a `text-align:center` and boxes should be `inline-block` elements, without any floats. That is if you need them centered horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flexible box solution. Set `display: flex` to parent element of the two boxes and then align them to center using `justify-content: center`.

Check the current browser compatibility table for [**flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
.table-1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box-1 {
  background: url(../images/_C008.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #374140;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>Au quotidien, la vie de l’atelier est organisée autour des tâches minutieuses de chacun et tous sont conscients que l’excellence est le résultat d’un travail d’équipe.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <p>Au quotidien, la vie de l’atelier est organisée autour des tâches minutieuses de chacun et tous sont conscients que l’excellence est le résultat d’un travail d’équipe.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
.table-1 > div{
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.box-1 {
  background: url(../images/_C008.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #374140;
  width: 32%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-1">
  <div class="box-1">
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
<p>Au quotidien, la vie de l’atelier est organisée autour des tâches minutieuses de chacun et tous sont conscients que l’excellence est le résultat d’un travail d’équipe.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle with my solution:

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/j8gwrbjp/)